# How to make simple form responsive?

Tags: sapui5

I have made a simple form which is defined below:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
        <f:SimpleForm id="SimpleFormChange480_12120"
                editable="true"
                layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
                title="Add New Employee"
                labelSpanL="4"
                labelSpanM="4"
                labelSpanS="12"
                adjustLabelSpan="false"
                emptySpanL="0"
                emptySpanM="0"
                emptySpanS="0"
                columnsL="1"
                columnsM="1"
                columnsS="1"
                singleContainerFullSize="false" >
            <f:content>
                <Label text="Employee Id">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Label>
                <Input id="empid">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M4 S12"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <Label text="Employee Name">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Label>
                <Input id="empname">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M4 S12"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <Label text="Email">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Label>
                <Input id="email">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M4 S12"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <Label text="Department">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Label>
                <Input id="department">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M4 S12"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <Label text="City">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Label>
                <Input id="city">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M4 S12"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <Label text="State">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Label>
                <Input id="state" >
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M4 S12"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <Label text="District">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Label>
                <Input id="district" >
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M4 S12"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <Label text="Address">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Label>
                <Input id="address" >
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M4 S12"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
            </f:content>
        </f:SimpleForm>
    </VBox>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

I guess I am doing any mistake in defining the `span`. I don't have much idea on large, medium and small systems I think the main problem I am facing is in that issue.

When I am checking the responsive in iPad device it's not showing exact responsive, but I have tried in this way can anyone help me to make it as responsive.

Comment: i want to achieve a form having multiple columns with 3 rows in responsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement(iPad), the form was not showing 3 columns. You need to adjust the `span` values.

```
<VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
    <f:SimpleForm id="SimpleFormChange480_12120"
        editable="true"
        layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
        title="Add New Employee"
        labelSpanL="4"
        labelSpanM="4"
        labelSpanS="12"
        adjustLabelSpan="false"
        emptySpanL="0"
        emptySpanM="0"
        emptySpanS="0"
        columnsL="1"
        columnsM="1"
        columnsS="1"
        singleContainerFullSize="false" >
        <f:content>
            <Label text="Employee Id">
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                </layoutData>
            </Label>
            <Input id="empid">
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                </layoutData>
            </Input>
            <Label text="Employee Name">
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                </layoutData>
            </Label>
            <Input id="empname">
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                </layoutData>
            </Input>
            <Label text="Email">
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                </layoutData>
            </Label>
            <Input id="email">
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                </layoutData>
            </Input>
            <Label text="Department">
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                </layoutData>
            </Label>
            <Input id="department">
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                </layoutData>
            </Input>
            <Label text="City">
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                </layoutData>
            </Label>
            <Input id="city">
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                </layoutData>
            </Input>
            <Label text="State">
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                </layoutData>
            </Label>
            <Input id="state" >
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                </layoutData>
            </Input>
            <Label text="District">
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                </layoutData>
            </Label>
            <Input id="district" >
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                </layoutData>
            </Input>
            <Label text="Address">
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                </layoutData>
            </Label>
            <Input id="address" >
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                </layoutData>
            </Input>
            <!-- Select -->
            <Label text="Branch">
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                </layoutData> 
            </Label>
            <Select> 
                <layoutData> 
                    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12" /> 
                </layoutData> 
            </Select>
        </f:content>
    </f:SimpleForm>
</VBox>
```

**Output - iPad with label span 2 and input span 3**

[image]

**Output - iPad with label and input span 2**

[image]

Comment: may i know why the labels names are truncating.... can we avoid that

Comment: As we are trying to achieve the 3 columns layout there is not much width for the labels which results in truncating the words. We can achieve it, but the input will be in smaller size. I have updated the code as well kindly refer it.

Comment: Thank yoiu  mate i have  tried and i got it but when i  add select box  for  input fields for example(i.e., department and city) in iphone 5 its not responsive may i know the reason behind that

Comment: same as above code just i have added select box <Label text="Branch"><layoutData> <l:GridData span="L2 M3 S6"/> </layoutData> </Label>
<Select> <layoutData> <l:GridData span="L2 M3 S6" /> </layoutData> </Select>